# How do I create an index over multiple fields using NHibernate 3.2 mapping by code?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

In NHibernate 3.2 mapping by code, you can index a given field like so:

```
mapper.Class<Customer>(map =>
{
    map.Property(x => x.Address, m => m.Index("AddressIndex"));
});
```

I'd like to create an index covering the following fields:

- Address
- FirstName
- LastName

I see no Index method on the 'map' object, nor do I see an overload on the property specific Index method that allows you to specify additional columns. How can I accomplish this?

Edit, I found that if I do the following:

```
mapper.Class<Customer>(map =>
{
    map.Property(x => x.Address, m => m.Index("AddressIndex"));
    map.Property(x => x.FirstName, m => m.Index("AddressIndex"));
    map.Property(x => x.LastName, m => m.Index("AddressIndex"));
});
```

An index is created covering all 3 columns, but not in the order I specified. Is there a way to specify the column order in the index?

Comment: Does order matter? I always was led to believe that the order doesn't matter as they are not key columns and stored in the leaf pages of the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If order does matter then one option is to create and execute a script after your schema has been generated.

I remember reading this about [composite indexes](http://colleenmorrow.com/2011/04/07/composite-indexes-does-column-order-matter/) and it seems order might or might **NOT** matter!

Comment: Order definitely matters. By putting the most selective column first (SQL only generates statistics on the first column in an index), SQL Server is able filter out the most junk up front. I don't know if this applies to other DB platforms or not. I still haven't figured this one out btw.

Comment: Then you will need to execute the script AFTER your schema has been generated.