# nHibernate and SQLServer: can I declare indexes from the mapping, or do I have to create them separately

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate

I have a simple mapping file:

```
<class name="Comment">
  <id name="ID" generator="increment" />
  <property name="KnowledgeID" />
</class>
```

where "KnowledgeID" is a foreign key to another table. I would like this to be indexed for performance reasons.
I know that I can create an index in SQL Server Management Studio and linking it through its name:

```
  <property name="KnowledgeID" index="IX_KnowledgeComment_ID" />
```

but I was wondering if I can reach the same goal through nHibernate configuration.

So, what's a good standard practice in defining indexes for nHibernate-generated tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can create indices or unique contraints with nHibernate.  Here's some syntax for unique constraints using mapping by code

```
public AgencyMap()
{
    Property(x => x.Name, m => 
    { 
        m.UniqueKey("UC_AgencyName");
        m.Index("IX_AgencyName");
        m.NotNullable(true); 
    });
    Property(x => x.ORI);
```

Here's a link to an example using a multiple column index

[How do I create an index over multiple fields using NHibernate 3.2 mapping by code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274288/how-do-i-create-an-index-over-multiple-fields-using-nhibernate-3-2-mapping-by-co)

Comment: Can this be done only with the Fluent syntax, or there is a way of achieving the same using XML mappings?

Comment: Yes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834565/how-to-create-a-multi-column-index-or-unique-constraint-with-nhibernate